# C# anonymous object (javascript like) for adhoc usage. No class definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, object

I wanted to create an anonymous C# object with no class definition. Similar to javascript object. Sample code **not working**:

```
var data = new
  {
    groups = new object[] {
      new {
        header = "Facebook",
        buttons = new object[] {
          new {
            label = "Create new post"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: And what´s the question?

Comment: I was about to ask and found it out myself. So just wanted to share the solution.

Comment: Than you should either delete your question or write it in a manner that helps the community. But with your current question there is no chance to help ypu out on this topic. Since the problem was a simple typo I vote for closing this question.

Comment: For me it is more of a conceptual mistake, not a typo. I actually thought this was the correct way

Comment: It actually helped me. I found it by googling adhoc object c# and got this question. I'm rewriting it to confirm with SO  guidelines.

Answer (score 6):

The problem was the `new object[]`. It is just `new []`. Working code:

```
var data = new
  {
    groups = new [] {
      new {
        header = "Facebook",
        buttons = new [] {
          new {
            label = "Create new post"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
```